# How to configure Jenkins pipeline so that if there are multiple shell scripts and if one fails the jenkins jobs still runs instead of exiting

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to configure a Jenkins pipeline job so that it should be able to run multiple shell script jobs. Even if one shell script fails the job should run the other two before failing the job.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tweak your shell script, not Jenkins pipeline to achieve what you want!

Try this in your shell script

> shell script command > /dev/null 2>&1 || true

so fail/pass it will execute and go to next shell script

Comment: and lets say it fails..so it will move to the next script and at the end the overall jenkins job will be failed...right?

Answer (score 0):

You can always try catch the potentially failing sh execution

```
node {
    sh "echo test"
    try {
        sh "/dev/null 2>&1"
    } catch (error) {
        echo "$error"
    }
    sh "echo test1"
}
```

Above runs successfully and produces

```
Started by user Blazej Checinski
[Pipeline] node
Running on agent2 in /home/build/workspace/test
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
[test] Running shell script
+ echo test
test
[Pipeline] sh
[test] Running shell script
+ /dev/null
/home/build/workspace/test@tmp/durable-b4fc2854/script.sh: line 2: /dev/null: Permission denied
[Pipeline] echo
hudson.AbortException: script returned exit code 1
[Pipeline] sh
[test] Running shell script
+ echo test1
test1
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Answer (score 0):

Use returnStatus from sh step
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#sh-shell-script

In this way your script will always pass and the status result will be stored in the variable on which you can put a check later and throw an exception mentioning a failure in x stage

or wrap your sh steps in WarnError so the stage will become yellow and not raise any failure (the colored stage will be visible on pipeline page)